# Changing values of variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to this, I want to change the value of a variable when the button is fired.
I have an array selectedValues, which contains a status of a project i.e Ready/NotReady.

What I want to do is to change the status to Not Ready if the status is Ready and vice versa.

I want a js function to do this. I was wondering if I could do it like this?

```
 $scope.changeStatus = function(selectedValue){
    if(selectedValue.status == "Not_Ready")
    selectedValue.status = "Ready"
}
```

Comment: yes you can do this. what is the problem

Comment: You aren't changing the value of a variable, you're assigning a value to a property of an object (Arrays are Objects).

Comment: @RobG so how can i perform it?

Comment: I would suggest. use boolean if there are only two cases. then it will become more easier. true for ready and false if not ready

Comment: can you post a plunker?

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.changeStatus = function(selectedValue){
    selectedValue.status == "Not_Ready" ? selectedValue.status = "Ready" : selectedValue.status = "Not_Ready"
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

If you ever add more statuses that you'd like to cycle through, you can do something like this:

```
$scope.changeStatus = function(selectedValue) {
    var statuses = ['State_A', 'State_B', 'State_C', 'State_D', 'State_E'];

    selectedValue.status = statuses[(statuses.indexOf(selectedValue.status) + 1) % statuses.length];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this as well :

```
$scope.changeStatus = function(){
    if($scope.selectedValue.status == "Not_Ready"){
        $scope.selectedValue.status = "Ready"
    }else{
        $scope.selectedValue.status = "Not_Ready"
    }
}
```

Comment: you just added else block in my way of doing. nothing else.

Comment: Yes, and you'll need to as $scope before selected value as well.

Comment: you mean $scope.selectedValue?

Comment: Yes. Only selectedValue will be limited to function, but $scope.selectedValue will be in whole controller

Comment: in the parameter ?